# JSF - Button Double Click

Tags: button, jsf-2, double-click, right-click

My JSF application need to create a custom keyboard. Then I want to get `Double Click` or `Right Click` action on JSF `Button` to define keys.

Is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a library called Prime Faces , you can use that.
http://primefaces.org/downloads.html

It has a number of built in components that you can use in JSF (one of which  allows you to create a custom keyboard.)

Comment: Poor answer. The minimum you could have done here is recommend a specific component